# What is the etiquette of providing more than one answer to the same question?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I am thinking specifically of [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/are-there-any-specific-teaching-techniques-to-handle-virtual-classroom-session#comment4504_2772), where my answer would be wholly different based on the type of virtual teaching environment. I would like to provide separate answers for each environment so that they can be evaluated (and voted on) separately. Some answers may be more useful than others.

I know that I have the ability to provide more than one answer to a question. If the two answers are substantively different, is that preferable to a single long, rambling answer of the type "In situation A, do this, ............ and in situation B..... this other thing"?

Comment: From the main SO.meta, it seems that the preferred method is to [put both answers in one answer, using headers to distinguish them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28471/139256).

Comment: I'm with eykanal on this one. Don't use multiple answers to a single question unless there's no other option. You can use the headers to distinguish different parts of your answer, so you should do so, rather than creating multiple answers.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to prefer them being put in the same answer using headers or bullet points or something to distinguish them for a few reasons:

1. Two 50-point answers does not a gold badge make ;)
2. If you provide two excellent answers, it removes any conflict about which one to accept as "the" answer
3. It keeps your two-part answer together, so that variation in voting doesn't split them off. This is less of a big deal if they can truly be separated with no harm done, but I find this to be fairly rare.
4. It makes referring to @CleverUser's answer somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The vote is done to the answer as a whole. You would probably get higher votes for a more complete answer, or even several answers.